# reliable way to send emails (web development)

Tags: php, email, web-applications

I'm working on a site that allows users to signup up. I'm currently using php to send activation links to users who sign up. It's just that I've noticed the email doesn't always arrive on time and sometimes, it doesn't even arrive at all. I'd much rather use PHP but with this issue, I can't.

Anyone have some suggestions on alternatives that can also interact with PHP?

Comment: dont have an activation link, activation is not confirmation of email address, it is only confirmation that one has been created.  also you probably wont go far wrong using SPF records and txt records for the domain and state what IP address email comes from so that it is not treated as rogue, also if your on a shared host its possible the mail is blacklisted.

Comment: @minus4 : I think you wanted to say "ip is blacklisted", +1 for your comment.

Comment: I don't think there is any blacklisting involved because i use the same email address for testing and some times it arrives, sometimes it doesn't. If it was blacklisted, it wouldn't arrive at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [PHP Class: MIME E-mail message sending](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/9-PHP-PHP-mailer-to-compose-and-send-MIME-messages.html). It's pretty well documented and [ranks 1st on phpclasses.org](http://www.phpclasses.org/browse/top/top.html#ratedpackages)

Comment: If it's arriving "slow", the problem isn't likely to be the PHP code itself.